# Maven Build error "Expected root element project but found html"

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I am new to maven. I am trying to build a project given to me. But I keep getting the following error. I have deleted the .m2 directory multiple times with no luck.

I read through a few post suggestions the ISP was sending HTML file instead of HTTP code.

Here is a log from the run.

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
 [WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.psystems:ps-framework instead of com.psystems:super-pom, please verify your project structure @ line 2, column 10
 [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /root/.m2/repository/com/psystems/super-pom/1.0.0/super-pom-1.0.0.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen ..." "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>... @1:127)  @ /root/.m2/repository/com/psystems/super-pom/1.0.0/super-pom-1.0.0.pom, line 1, column 127

at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:672)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:663)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:250)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
  [ERROR]   
  [ERROR]   The project com.psystems:ps-etl-framework:3.2.19-SNAPSHOT (/home/hadoop/proclitivity/etl/pom.xml) has 1 error
  [ERROR]     Non-parseable POM /root/.m2/repository/com/psystems/super-pom/1.0.0/super-pom-1.0.0.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen ..." "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>... @1:127)  @ /root/.m2/repository/com/psystems/super-pom/1.0.0/super-pom-1.0.0.pom, line 1, column 127 -> [Help 2]
 org.apache.maven.model.io.ModelParseException: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen ..." "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>... @1:127) 
at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:453)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:864)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:411)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:380)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:344)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:672)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:663)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:250)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen ..." "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>... @1:127) 
at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.read(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:4348)
at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.read(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:560)
at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:118)
... 24 more
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
 [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

Comment: it looks like the dependency you are looking for ( is it hosted in an in-house repository? ) is not setup correctly the repository is returning an HTML page saying this resource is not found when you're expecting a pom or a jar file...

Comment: I don't think so. This is my pom file:-
https://github.com/morfious902002/java/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: "Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' " Maven is seeing an HTML file instead of a POM.

Comment: You are right. After deleting the repo and connecting to the internal network I was able to get the proper dependency.